# Search index of tuples for element in pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which I sort to find the unique combinations of rows.

```
    In[0]: df = pd.DataFrame([['cow',0],['chicken',0],
                   ['cow',1],
                   ['chicken',3],['pig',3],['cow',3],
                   ['pig',4],['cow',4],['chicken',4]]
                   ,columns=['animals','farm_id'])
    In[1]: df
    Out[1]: 
                 animals  farm_id
          0      cow        0
          1  chicken        0
          2      cow        1
          3  chicken        3
          4      pig        3
          5      cow        3
          6      pig        4
          7      cow        4
          8  chicken        4

    In[2]: df = df.groupby('farm_id')['animals'].unique().apply(lambda x: 
                   tuple(sorted(x))).reset_index()

    In[3]: df = df.groupby('animals').agg({'farm_id':'count'})
```

This gives me what I want, which is a count of the unique combinations where the order does not matter:

```
    In[4]: df

    Out[4]: 
                             farm_id
        animals                     
        (chicken, cow)             1
        (chicken, cow, pig)        2
        (cow,)                     1
```

Now, I would like to search through my tuple indices to find a single element. If I search for 'chicken' for instance, I want to return only the rows that mention 'chicken':

```
                     farm_id
animals                     
(chicken, cow)             1
(chicken, cow, pig)        2
```

How can I search through the tuple indices and return only the rows that mention a certain element, regardless of the placement of the element? My actual dataset is quite large so efficiency is key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and specify the axis as the index.

Filter can also use regex read about in the docs for more info.

```
df.filter(like='chicken',axis=0)

                     farm_id
animals                     
(chicken, cow)             1
(chicken, cow, pig)        2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Is there a similar way to search a sub-tuple instead of searching for a string? In this example, I would want to search for (chicken,cow) and return every row that mentions chicken OR cow OR both.

Comment: @BenjaminLatimer yep try `df.filter(regex='chicken|pig',axis=0)` you need to use `bitwise OR` `|`